# "This template uses shell, which has not been supported for UWP yet."

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I don't know if this is a relatively new issue but whenever I develop a cross platform app and choose the target types (iOS, Android, or UWP) it doesn't let me select UWP and says this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Quite strange...

Goodbye

Comment: From MS's Website: Xamarin.Forms Shell is fully available on iOS and Android, but only partially available on the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). In addition, Shell is currently experimental on UWP and can only be used by adding the following line of code to the App class in your UWP project, before calling Forms.Init: For information on how to add a UWP project to a Xamarin.Forms solution, see Setup Windows Projects. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction#platform-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabbed and Flyout template is not available for UWP currently but you can develop all platforms in Blank template.
[image]

Comment: I still cannot check UWP even with the blank template ...

Comment: @freezing_ Did you install the "Universal Windows Platform Development" workload? That did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be possible now (as of *Visual Studio Enterprise 2019*, Version 16.11.16) if you have the "Universal Windows Platform Development" component installed (as @Christoph_Lipka pointed out) - although the note is still there that it is experimental:

[image]